# HtmlResponse is not supported on this device

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have developed interactive canvas application and it was working fine with devices having display.

Suddenly when I checked it today it says "Application is not responding, try again later.". When I checked in test simulator and gone through debug I have received following error printed in debug.

```
"sharedDebugInfoList": [
  {
    "name": "ResponseValidation",
    "debugInfo": "",
    "subDebugEntryList": [
      {
        "name": "MalformedResponse",
        "debugInfo": "expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[1].html_response: HtmlResponse is not supported on this device..",
        "subDebugEntryList": []
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

It was working and users were using it in their mobile device, but this sudden error made me blind to understand it. I have not made even 1 line of change in my code. I have even checked cloud logs and there is nothing. Here is what I am doing when user enters in my action.

```
app.intent('welcome', (conv) => {
    console.log('capabilities = ',conv.surface.capabilities)
    if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
        conv.close('Sorry, this device does not support Interactive Canvas!');
        return;
    }
    conv.ask(`Welcome! Let's start the game`);
    conv.ask(new HtmlResponse({
       url: '<url of my website having interactive canvas support>',
    }));
});
```

[Here](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000066d8b773f) is the action that I am facing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action seems to be working ok for me.

The most common reason I've seen for it not working is that the category wasn't set to "Games & Fun" (or was cleared for some reason) or the Interactive Canvas checkbox wasn't set.

To make sure you are still in the "Games & Fun" category, go to the Actions Console, the "Deploy" tab, and the "Directory" information.

[image: Setting category]

Then, towards the bottom of that same page, make sure you have the Interactive Canvas checkbox set.

[image]

Comment: That worked Allen, thanks a lot. Is this because of new update of console? Because it was working under Education category perfectly fine.

Comment: First of all - Glad it worked! If it has helped, accepting or upvoting the answer is always appreciated.

Comment: It may have been that they opened up the Interactive Canvas for Education for a while (it certainly makes sense that they do so!), but as far as I'm aware, they always required "Fun & Games" to be set for the checkbox to even be visible. It is possible that with recent updates, they realized they left it open for Education and then closed it.